# mass update of primary keys along with foreign keys

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, primary-key, database-migration

Here is a sample

```
CREATE TABLE A(ida int PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE B(idb int PRIMARY KEY, ida int);
ALTER TABLE B 
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_B_ida FOREIGN KEY (ida) REFERENCES A(ida);

INSERT INTO A (ida) VALUES (1);

INSERT INTO B (idb, ida) VALUES (1, 1);

BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE A 
SET ida = ida + 1000;

UPDATE B 
SET ida = ida + 1000;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

When running the part between `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT TRANSACTION` (all 4 lines), I get an error

> Msg 547 - UPDATE instruction conflicts with FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_B_ida"

In the context of a data migration project (merging 2 dbs with the same schema), I need to mass update primary keys (to avoid collisions) and make sure foreign keys follow.

What is the recommended way to do this?

I was thinking, I could offset keys during copy, but that might make the copy script complex (difficult to avoid listing column names)

Comment: If you need to update the primary keys then I would suggest that it was the wrong choice as a primary key, if I am honest. You'll be best dropping the primary key constraints, doing your changes, and then re-enabling the constraint afterwards.

Comment: _In the context of a data migration project_ You should do that conversion in the actual movement of rows from one table to the other in the appropriate order to handle dependencies. Not by directly updating existing rows directly (at least not without a good reason).

Comment: It makes sense, but if you write SELECT idb, ida + 1000 AS ida FROM B, you have to name all columns, and there are a bunch of them.

Comment: That is why I am attracted by a solution that separates the update on the one side, and the plain simple copy on the other side. It might be doomed, though

Comment: "Naming columns" - which can be generated dynamically from the metadata or dragged onto a column window from Object Explorer - is a very poor excuse for discarding a potential solution.

Comment: It might be doomed => It seems to be doomed. Almost RIP

Comment: Why is it doomed? The only thing preventing this from working is a list of columns for your insert which is incredibly simple to generate.

Comment: metadata + STRING_AGG I guess

Comment: Just grab the columns folder in object explorer and drag it into a query window. All column names will appear properly comma separated. Then just change the one column you want to change and you are done.

Comment: So, to merge db1 and db2 sharing the schema SCH, I can create db3 and intialize its schema to SCH, copy the data from db1 into db3 and in the process offset PKs and FKs. To do this I need to respect the dependency order as explained by Smor. Then I will end up with what I want in db3. Then I have to copy the data from db3 into db2.

Comment: Thx everyone, it's been usefull.